# Fedora 22 rsync on root vs package reinstall

Tags: backup

I know that backup issues are heavily queried, but I am looking for problems that experienced Linux users have encountered, re the 3 issues shown below.  Unfortunately, these (long winded) issues mutally interact, so I couldn't split this into separate queries.  Although I specifically use Fedora 22, I welcome Fedora-generic or linux-generic responses.  Issues:

(Issue 1) Suppose that:

a. My boot drive is (device = sda) and my docking station houses a backup hard drive (device = sdc).

b. I have already used a recent version of Fedora22 Live to install the (full) Fedora22 on (device = sdc), making sdc bootable.

c. I want to maintain sdc as a full backup (i.e. a functional "clone") in case sda goes bad, TOTALLY RELYING on periodic rsync's of the sda-root against sdc to keep sdc current.

d. I want to be able to both boot the backup from the docker (position sdc) or replace the original boot disk with the backup, booting the backup in (position sda).

e. I want to TOTALLY AVOID having to reinstall any packages.

My Fedora 22 boot drive has the following directory structure:

.autorelabel, bin, boot, .config, dev, etc, home, lib, lib32, lib64, lost+found, media, mnt, opt, proc, root, run, sbin, srv, sys, tmp, usr, var

My tentative list of directories to exclude is:

/dev, /home, /media, /mnt, /proc, /run/media, /sys, /tmp, /var/lock, /var/run

/home is excluded because I rsync it separately.  Under the assumptions of issue (1), I REQUEST DISCUSSION OF DIRECTORIES TO EXCLUDE.

(Issue 2) In my Linux-inexperience, and focusing on supposition (1)d above, I have speculated that /etc/fstab and /boot/grub2/grub.cfg may need special handling.  My intent is:

a. On sda, copy /etc/fstab to .../fstab_sda and copy /boot/grub2/grub.cfg to .../grub_sda.cfg.

b. Exclude /etc/fstab and /boot/grub2/grub.cfg from the rsync, HOPING that the backup will therefore boot successfully from (position sdc).

c. If I want to replace the boot disk with the backup (booting the backup from position sda), I will replace .../fstab and .../grub.cfg with their ..._sda counterparts, HOPING that the backup will therefore boot successfully from (position sda).

HAS ANYONE TAKEN THIS APPROACH?  DO .../fstab and .../grub.cfg ACTUALLY NEED THIS SPECIAL HANDLING?  ARE THERE ANY OTHER FILES THAT NEED THIS SPECIAL HANDLING?

(Issue 3) My research SUGGESTS that (1) + (2) above are overkill, and that I should abandon the rsync_on_the_root strategy in favor of:

a. Only rsync'g /home and /etc.

b. Maintaining a list of installed packages with dnf.

c. Restoring by using Fedora 22 Live to place the (full) Fedora 22 on a new disk, manually rsync'g /home and /etc on this new disk, booting from this new disk, invoking the automatic updates to this new disk, and then using dnf to manually re-install the packages to this new disk.

d. Periodically checking fedoraproject.org for a newer version of the Fedora 22 (workstation) Live iso.

On my system, "dnf history userinstalled" reports only 24 packages since my original Fedora 22 installation in June 2015.  I'm supposing that the vast majority of automatic updates are covered by fedoraproject.org's periodic update of the Fedora 22 (workstation) Live iso.

TO EXPERIENCED LINUX USERS:

DO YOU AGREE WITH MY INFERENCES IN (3) ABOVE, WHICH MAKES (1) AND (2) ABOVE OBSELETE?  I'VE SEEN COMMENTS THAT (3)c MAY TAKE MORE THAN 24 HOURS.  DOES (3)d ABOVE PREVENT THAT?

ALSO, DOES (3)c RESULT IN A HARD DISK THAT MAY BE BOOTED FROM EITHER (position sdc, the docking station) OR (position sda, the main boot drive)?

ALTERNATIVELY, EVEN ASSUMING THAT "dnf history userinstalled" REPORTS LESS THAN 100 PACKAGES, AND THAT (3)d IS OBSERVED, MIGHT (3)c STILL TAKE MORE THAN 24 HOURS?  IF SO, WHY?

ARE (1) + (2) ABOVE FOOLPROOF FOR FEDORA 22?  WHAT PROBLEMS HAVE YOU ENCOUNTERED/HEARD-OF RE (1) + (2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prefer to keep a list of installed packages (e.g. output of `rpm -qa`) somewhere safe, and sync `/home` (end stash a copy of `/etc` away). In case of need, reinstall and install the installed packages, and compare `/etc` to to copy, fixing any required changes).

The reason is that this is safer than a homegrown "clone my system" set of scripts. It might be slower (but you won't do this exactly daily, I hope), but if reinstall fails you can start over. If the clone didn't work correctly, you'll find out *after* the original is hosed.